# Extra border value added in css

Tags: css, ejs

Although I specified the "border: 1 px", inspecting in the Firebug reveals some extra added value. Where is it coming from? I am using ejs on node.js.

[image: Screenshot from Firebug]

Comment: Do you have some jQuery/JavaScript that are manipulating CSS styles on the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can see in the image you provided,
apparently you have a stylesheet file named `reset.css` and another one that starts with `reserv` and end with `js.css`.

did you added them to your page?
do you apply inline-styling to your elements?

check your scripts to see if a function apply this border after the page loads..

If you want you style to 'win' over the inline-style, add `!important` to the rules.
like:

```
div
{
    border: 1px solid black !important;
}
```

Comment: might be that a js that does it. Could not track it down, so I fixed it in the css by adjusting the values. Even though the JS changes the values in the css, the firebug should have shown that value in the "div.book" instead of 1px, shouldn't it?

Comment: no, because inline CSS win over the external. see my updated answer.